# How quasirandom are the nonabelian finite simple groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

A group is $d$-quasirandom if every nontrivial complex representation has dimension at least $d$. Gowers introduced quasirandomness in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3877) and proved that every nonabelian finite simple group of order $n$ is $\sqrt{\log n}/2$-quasirandom.

**Question:** What is the correct (asymptotic) lower bound for the quasirandomness of nonabelian finite simple groups?

Gowers indicates that a theorem of Jordan (Theorem 14.12 [here](https://www.cefns.nau.edu/%7Efalk/classes/511/Isaacs_Character_theory.pdf)) implies a slightly better bound. Indeed, this theorem gives that a nonabelian simple group of order $n$ has a nontrivial representation of dimension $d$ only if $n\leq (d!)12^{d(\pi(d+1)+1)}$, which implies that these groups are $\Omega(\sqrt{\log n\log\log n})$-quasirandom.

Of course, the correct bound should be obtainable using the classification of finite simple groups. The sporadic groups are irrelevant to the asymptotics, and the alternating groups are $\Omega(\log n/\log\log n)$-quasirandom. It remains to study the groups of Lie type. What I want can be read off the first column of the generic character tables of these groups, but to my surprise, these aren't known yet (see LeechLattice's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391136/is-the-representation-of-finite-simple-groups-fully-understood/)). Interestingly, the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400864/is-operatornamepsl2-q-the-most-quasirandom-group) describes how to find an upper bound on the smallest nontrivial representation in these cases, whereas I want a lower bound.

Comment: A natural way of writing this is to ask for the largest finite simple subgroup of the unitary group $U(n)$, and the obvious guess is $A_{n+1}$.

Comment: For finite simple groups, rather than all finite groups, I think the minimal non-trivial *projective* dimension (i.e., dimension of a minimal representation of a central extension) is known explicitly. (There might be a couple of cases where it's not completely known down to the exact number, but I think for the complexes it is.) The papers you are looking for are the unique ones by Landazuri and Seitz, and a follow up by Seitz and Zalesski, There have been a few others since then, but their bounds are usually pretty good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a finite simple group of order $n$ with a nontrivial representation of degree $d$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $U(d)$. By Collins's sharp version of Jordan's theorem (https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/JGT.2007.032/html), $G$ has an abelian normal subgroup of index at most $(d+1)!$, which must be trivial since $G$ is simple, so $|G| \leq (d+1)!$. Rearranging, $d \gtrsim \log n / \log\log n$.

Collins's work builds on work of Weisfeiler that I think was unfinished by the time of his disappearance.

**Edit:** Specializing to simple $G$ actually reduces Collins's paper to a reference to a reference to the paper of Seitz and Zalesskii (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869383711324?via%3Dihub) mentioned by David Craven in the comments, so that's really the heart of the matter. We thereby get the slightly stronger bound $n \leq (d+1)!/2$ (for sufficiently large $d$). Apart from alternating groups I think you can read out a much stronger bound like $n \leq \exp O((\log d)^2)$, or $d \geq \exp \Omega( (\log n)^{1/2})$ (I am guessing the next worst case is $\mathrm{SL}_n(2)$).

Comment: Ah, it hadn't occurred to me that this theorem of Jordan would have a Wikipedia article that contains the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Schur_theorem